# unstable svn connections: 'propfind of 'xxx' could not connect to server'

Tags: svn, networking

Recently I've had an complaint by a user that the subversion server I'm using is unable to create stable connections i.e. 'PROPFIND of xxx: could not connect to server'. The behavior appears to be random sometimes it gives the error, sometimes things go smoothly.

To address the issue I ran svnadmin verify to check for the integrity of the repo it indicates there are no problems, fiddling around with timeout values of apache.   I've consulted an network administrator for clarification and he confirmed it's most probably not network related.

I'm inclined to say the problem is not server related, but i wont exclude it. Several other people have confirmed to have had no problems however. And the web-interface hosted on the same servers is reachable by the user.

I find the problem to be quite troubling to resolve due lack being able to replicate it myself. I'm hoping some of you can provide some insight how i can resolve the issue.

Comment: This problem appears to be an ongoing intermittent issue on the "WordPress" end.   Appears that at least on of their servers goes offline.  Likely the result of a cluster our round-robin setup with a bad mirror.

No word from the WordPress people on this, but is comes up fairly regularly lately.

Answer (score 1):

See [Can't connect to Wordpress SVN server to update repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524177/cant-connect-to-wordpress-svn-server-to-update-repository/8546854#8546854)

If you are on Comcast they appear to be blocking access to the WordPress repo.

Comment: We are finding multiple people with the same issue and have started tracking the problem on our blog:
http://www.cybersprocket.com/2011/tips-tricks/is-comcast-playing-big-brother-with-your-internet/